# Replacing parts of a list item with inputs from a form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, list, replace

I am trying to create an edit feature for my menu editor. I get the proper values, place them in the form text boxes, and then am trying to replace the current text with the new text.

First, the user clicks on the 'edit' button and this function is called:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("editing");
        var menulink = $(this).next().find('a').attr('href');
        var menudisplay = $(this).next().find('a:first').text();
        $("#editlink").val(menulink);
        $("#editdisplay").val(menudisplay);
    });
```

Then the form is displayed in a popup box with the values inserted:

```
<div id="edit-box" class="login-popup">
        <a href="#" class="close"><img src="../../../images/close5.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>
        Enter the link for the menu item: <input type="text" id="editlink" /><br />
        Enter the text to display: <input type="text" id="editdisplay" /><br />
        <button id="saveEdit">Save Menu Item</button>
    </div>
```

Then the user clicks the save button and this function is called:

```
$("#saveEdit").click(function(){
    var editlink = $("#editlink").val();
    var editdisplay = $("#editdisplay").val();
    **/* REPLACE THE CURRENT INFORMATION WITH THE NEW INFORMATION */**
    $('#mask, .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
        $(".edit").removeClass("editing");
        $('#mask').remove();  
    }); 
    $('.tree_item').each(function(){
        $(".delete, .edit").remove();
    });
    $.post('edit-menu-process.php', 
        {tree: $('#nav').html()}, 
        function(data){$("#printOut").html(data);}
    );
    alert("Menu item has been edited.");
    location.reload();
});
```

I am having trouble replacing the proper parts of the list item. I have bolded the area that I need to come up with code for. The rest of this function is getting the new values, getting rid of the mask and the class and the buttons, posting to the save process, and reloading the page. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

An example of the list item:

```
<li class="tree_item"><span><a href="index.php" class="menulink">Home</a></span></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the shown code is in the same namespace (bonuspoints if it's not the global one :)) you could do this by simply declaring a variable in that common namespace and assign the jQuery object in the first handler.

When the user now clicks edit they get assigned and are also accessible in your second handler.

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    var $link;

    $(".edit").click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $link = $this.next().find('a:first').attr('href');
        var menulink    = $link.attr('href');
        var menudisplay = $link.text();

        $this.addClass("editing");

        $("#editlink").val(menulink);
        $("#editdisplay").val(menudisplay);
    });

    $("#saveEdit").click(function(){
        var editlink = $("#editlink").val();
        var editdisplay = $("#editdisplay").val();

        // Update href attr and text of your link
        $link.attr('href', editlink);
        $link.text(editdisplay);

        $('#mask, .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
            $(".edit").removeClass("editing");
            $('#mask').remove();  
        }); 
        $('.tree_item').each(function(){
            $(".delete, .edit").remove();
        });
        $.post('edit-menu-process.php', 
            {tree: $('#nav').html()}, 
            function(data){$("#printOut").html(data);}
        );
        alert("Menu item has been edited.");
        location.reload();
    });
}(jQuery, this))
```

OT: You should try to avoid  [pool jumping](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-jquery-newbs-stop-jumping-in-the-pool/)

Comment: Just a clarifying question: why does `$link` AND `menulink` (and when updating href) have `.attr`. Is there a reason to put it in both places or is that just how it works? What is better about this way vs the way I posted right above this?

Comment: and these are all in a `document.ready(function(){`. I suppose another question would be what's the difference between mine and yours? A lot of questions. My apologies.

Comment: `menulink` doesn't have `.attr, it only contains the value from `$link`'s href attribute. With the `$()` function you'll get a reference to the HTML Node you're accessing wrapped in a jQuery object, that jQuery object provides the `.attr` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to figure out a way to make it work. Since `.text` seems to erase everything between the `li` tags, I can just replace everything using the variables.
`$(".editing").next().text('<span><a href="'+editlink+'" class="menulink">'+editdisplay+'</a></span>');`